# This program takes a number of elements of an array, (positive numbers only), and sorts them from smallest to largest

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, function-definition, selection-sort

How does the function sort work. And what parameters does this pass into the write function so that it writes out numbers from smallest to largest. The for in a for loop part confuses me the most...
What do we need the "pom" for.

```
#define MAX 100

int read(double[]);
void sort(double[], int);
void write(double[], int);

int main()
{
    double niz[MAX];
    int n;
    n = read(niz);
    sort(niz, n);
    printf("Sorted:"); 
    write(niz, n);
    return 0;
}

int read(double niz[])
{
    int i, n;
    do 
    { 
        printf("n="); 
        scanf_s("%d", &n); 
    } while (n < 1 || n > MAX);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. broj: ", i + 1); 
        scanf_s("%lf", &niz[i]);
    }

    return n;
}

void sort(double niz[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (niz[i] > niz[j])
            {
                double pom = niz[i]; 
                niz[i] = niz[j]; 
                niz[j] = pom;
            }
}

void write(double niz[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(" %.2lf", niz[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's a selection sort. It puts the smallest value in the array in the first position. Then it puts the second smallest value in the second position. And so on.

Comment: "*What do we need the "pom" for*". It's a temporary variable needed for swapping two elements of an array. You can't swap elements without having something to hold one of the values whilst it is being overwritten by the other.

Comment: "*what parameters does this pass into the write function*". Same as for `sort`.

Answer (score 2):

This function

```
void sort(double niz[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (niz[i] > niz[j])
            {
                double pom = niz[i]; niz[i] = niz[j]; niz[j] = pom;
                
            }
}
```

implements the selection sort algorithm with redundant swaps.

For each element of the array selected in the outer for loop the followed elements in the inner for loop are compared with the selected element and if an element in the inner for loop is less than the selected element then the two elements are swapped.

```
double pom = niz[i]; niz[i] = niz[j]; niz[j] = pom;
```

the auxiliary variable `pom` is used to store temporary the value of element `niz[i]` that allows to swap the values of `niz[i]` and `niz[j]`.

for example of you have the array